# Get value of local variable from parent class?

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes :

```
class A {
    public function load() {
        $var = new some_class();
        return $var;
    }
}
```

and

```
class B extends A {
    public function test() {
        $this->load();
        $var->some_method(); // ERROR : variable "$var" does not exists
    }
}
```

I want to access the local variable `$var` of the class "A" from class "B", how can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just fill $var with `$this->load();`

```
class B extends A {
    public function test() {
        $var = $this->load();
        $var->some_method(); // WORKS
    }
}
```

Comment: it did follow what OP ask for